# Can't log into Ubuntu 14.04. tried various solutions already

Tags: 14.04, login, unity-greeter

So I came to start up my computer as usual and was prompted to log in unusually. I couldn't log into my account or the guest account. It just kept bringing me back to the log in screen. I then searched for solutions, of which I tried

```
sudo chmod -R u+w /home/[username]
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx /home/[username]
chown -R [user-name]:[user-name] /home/[user-name]
sudo mv .Xauthority .XauthorityBak
```

None of these worked so I then created a live usb with boot repair on it, but still nothing.

These might make sense to some people though:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/12336440
http://paste.ubuntu.com/12336605

How can I fix this login issue?

Comment: Your fixes were rather making everything worse than solving the problem. One may not just `chown -R` its home directory or set permissions equally to all files in there. Some special files/directories need special permissions or to be owned by root to work!

Comment: Yep, I can understand that. You may realise, that I'm not completely Linux savvy. I tend to search for solutions and then just throw them into the terminal.

Comment: I know and I've already seen many doing that mistake. I'm currently writing a question myself on how to revert such mistakes easily:  http://askubuntu.com/q/672907/367990

Comment: So, do you think that I have changed certain things that I shouldn't have and that reversing them will be an issue?

Comment: Reversing them will solve the additional problem (that is maybe not noticeable yet) you created by trying those "fixes". The original problem will still be there though, but I am not sure about how to approach that yet. You should definitely restore the xauthority file: `cp /home/YOURUSERNAME/.XauthorityBak /home/YOURUSERNAME/.Xauthority`. That will also keep your backup copy.

Comment: ok I've done that. have been reading possible solutions all day, but can't quite get anything to change. Looks like I will go in via a USB ubuntu and back up the files I want and then install from new.

Answer (score -1):

try to install

`sudo apt-get install gdm`

and

`sudo apt-get install lightdm`

Comment: tried those two. the gdm came back with unable to locate package gdm and the lightdm came back with sub process /usr/bin/dpkg returned error code (1)